# How to traverse one level up in a binary search tree?

Tags: python, tree, binary-search-tree

I have a program in which I'm recursively traversing through a binary search tree. But, once I get to a particular node, I want to go to its parent and insert a node between the two. So how would I access the parent node?

Thank you.

Edit: 
I created a tree using an array, so for example:

```
tree = ['D', 'Does it have 4 legs?', 
       ['D', 'Can you ride it?', ['I','horse'], ['I', 'dog']], 
       ['D', 'Does it have hands?', ['I', 'monkey'],['I', 'bird']]]
```

My code for traversing through the tree:

```
def identify_thing(tree):
  node_type = tree[0]
  if node_type == "D":
    (question, yes_tree, no_tree) = tree[1:]
    yes_answer = get_yes_no(question)
    if yes_answer:
      identify_thing(yes_tree)
    else:
      identify_thing(no_tree)
  elif node_type == "I":
    name = tree[1]
    question = "Is it a {}?".format(name)
    yes_answer = get_yes_no(question)
    if yes_answer:
      print("{} Identified!".format(name))
    else:
      print("I don't know what it is.")
      new_name = get_nonblank_str("What is it?")
      new_question = get_nonblank_str("Give me a question where yes means 
                   a '{}'" " and no means a '{}'".format(new_name, name))
    # this is where I am trying to insert the code for updating the tree
```

Comment: That depends on the particular implementation of "binary search tree" that you are using. There are many possibilities. Which one are you using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you designed your tree.  If children know their parents, then it is as simple as `node = node.parent`.   If the nodes are arranged in an array (like a minheap), the index of the parent can be computed as `node = (n - 1) // 2`.